# Rendering checkboxes based on one array, and checked elements based on the second array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

Expected effect:

Render 4 checkbox (from `this.state.people`):

Paul

**Martin**

Joseph

**Gregor**

---

Based on `this.state.peopleChecked` checked

Martin

Gregor

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-examples

At stackblitz, I have a problem installing react-bootstrap

I have rendered people - 4 checkboxes. How to mark Martin, Gregor among these 4 people based on the 'peopleChecked' array?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: [
        {
          'firstname': "Paul",
          'id': "1"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Martin",
          'id': "2"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Joseph",
          'id': "3"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Gregor",
          'id': "4"
        }
      ],
       peopleChecked: [
         {
          'firstname': "Martin",
          'id': "2"
        },
         {
          'firstname': "Gregor",
          'id': "4"
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.people.map(person => (
          <div key={person.id} className="mb-1">
            <Form.Check 
              type={'checkbox'}
              id={person.id}
              label={person.firstname}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd change the data structure, peopleChecked should be an array of id's that are checked or an object with the id as key and value true when checked. Then on the checkbox element you just pass `checked={peopleChecked.includes(id)}` for array or if you do the object that would be `checked={peopleChecked[id] === true}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<Form.Check 
  type={'checkbox'}
  id={person.id}
  label={person.firstname}
  checked={this.state.peopleChecked.some(({ id, firstname }) => (id === person.id && firstname === person.firstname))}
/>
```